# SAS adding variables using input command

Tags: sas

I am a complete novice of SAS.

The sas file I downloaded has the following lines.

```
 IF (&IYEAR=2001 AND &FQTR>=2) THEN DO;
     INFILE &FILE LRECL=6217; 
          INPUT    @1 NEWID 8.    @663 QINTRVMO $2.   @665 QINTRVYR $4. @331 FINLWT21 11.3
        @3221 LIFINSPQ 12.4 +0 LIFINSCQ 12.4 @3245 RETPENPQ 12.4  +0 RETPENCQ 12.4 @1445 FDMAPPQ 12.4 +0 FDMAPCQ 12.4;
```

It's choosing which variables to use from the Consumer Expenditure Survey.

But I can't understand its logic.

**First**, what does

```
@3221 LIFINSPQ 12.4 +0 LIFINSCQ 12.4
```

mean?

The variables list is here: http://www.bls.gov/cex/2010/csxintvw.pdf

And it says the following.

[image]

So, "@3221" seems to refer to the variable's starting point.

But what are "12.4" and "+0"  ?

**Second**, what does

```
@663 QINTRVMO $2.
```

mean?

[image]

From this picture it seems "663" is the variable starting point.

But what does "$2" mean? Why do we need that?

Comment: I believe those are formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@3221 LIFINSPQ 12.4 +0 LIFINSCQ 12.4
```

You are correct that `@3221` tells the SAS file pointer where to look for that variable.

`12.4` is the informat, how should SAS read the variable.  Use the next 12 spaces of which expect 4 behind the decimal.

`+0` is another pointer control.  Because the next variable starts right after the previous, you are telling SAS not to advance the pointer.  Just pick up where you left off reading.

```
@663 QINTRVMO $2.
```

`$2.` is another informat.  Here you are telling SAS this is a character variable (`$`) and it is 2 characters wide.